# Numpy: Adding specific columns of rows conditionally

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

For a given numpy array:

```
[[1, 1, 'IGNORE_THIS_COL', 100],
 [1, 1, 'IGNORE_THIS_COL', 101],
 [1, 2, 'IGNORE_THIS_COL', 100]]
```

Is it possible to sum the rows (and columns conditionally)? Say column 0 is group and column 1 is user, then I would like to add the fourth column accordingly. The final 'summed' array should look like this.

```
[[1, 1, 'IGNORE_THIS_COL', 201],
 [1, 2, 'IGNORE_THIS_COL', 100]]
```

I have already checked multiple answers, including [Numpy: conditional sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50121980/numpy-conditional-sum).

Comment: Is ignore this column an integer? Or is it a string?

Comment: @user3483203 In this case it is an integer. Does that change the solution?

Comment: Very much so, otherwise numpy would cast all to strings when you created the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a groupby on a subset of columns. This is a challenge to implement with numpy, but is straightforward with a pandas `groupby`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(array)
out = df.groupby([0, 1], as_index=False).agg({2:'first', 3:'sum'}).values.tolist()
```

```
print(out)
[[1, 1, 'IGNORE_THIS_COL', 201], [1, 2, 'IGNORE_THIS_COL', 100]]
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `2:'first'` in the aggregation?

Comment: @DaveIdito You wanted to ignore the column, so I'm ignoring it by just taking the first value from it per group.